# Get call time in Skype for Business

Tags: c#, office365, skype, microsoft-graph-api, skype-for-business

I am using the Microsoft Graph API to collect basic information about a user's meetings and emails. Now, I also want to know how many phone calls (and chats) a user has in Skype for Business and how long the phone calls are.

I realized that Outlook creates a folder 'Conversation History' where these are logged. Unfortunately, not all call entries contain the call duration. I didn't find out when it is there and when not. Does someone know why this is?

And is there a way to get Skype for Business call durations?
(I think using the Lync-API (UCMA) might be a bit of an overkill)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like this as well.  I have added it to the suggestions page for Office 365.   https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273494-outlook-and-calendar/suggestions/13733040-call-duration-for-outgoing-calls-in-conversation-h

Comment: It's basically ridiculous that Skype for Business don't offer this. It was in Skype for ever, it's a fundamental detail of any phone conversation. I need to know it for charging clients.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the [Call detail recording (CDR)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj688079.aspx) database (when enabled).  You can find the [CDR Scheme here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398570.aspx).